# How to access remote index in search_api?

Tags: search

I have two drupal installations, one instance contains **data** like entities. The other one access this entities with service-calls and display the website.

I would like to make the entities searchable for users with search_api(_solr) and created an index in the **data** server which contains the entities.

Now.. How can I access this index from the other drupal installation? I found the [services_search_api](https://drupal.org/project/services_search_api) module, but there is only a DEV Version :-(

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: the fact it's dev is not bad. The fact it's minimally maintained, maintenance fixes only is.

Comment: You're right, I've used the DEV code and after reading the Issue Queue and applying patches, it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [services_search_api](https://drupal.org/project/services_search_api) Module is the right way, but you have to apply patches from the following Issues:

- [Support keys](https://drupal.org/node/1991936): provide Key Field for searching Solr Indexes. See Comment #1
- [Undefined functions](https://drupal.org/node/1889844): add required functions from previous Services Module. See Comment #4